# Can not figure out how to increment a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, increment

So, basically what I want to do with my code is make it so that a user can enter in a value, and then the program will add whatever value that would be to ALL the values in the array

//my code

```
{
    //creates array called table
    int[][] table = new int [10][10];

    //load the table with values
    for (int row=0; row < table.length; row++)
        for (int col=0; col < table[row].length; col++)
            table[row][col] = row * 10 + col;

    //Print the table
    for (int row=0; row < table.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col < table[row].length; col++)
            System.out.print (table[row][col] + "\t");
        System.out.println();

int incr;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("What do you want to increment by?");
incr = scan.nextInt();


for (int row=0; row < table.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col < table[row].length; col++)
            System.out.print (table[row][col] + "\t");

       System.out.println();



    }
}
```

That is my code so far, and I'm not sure where to go from here. If someone could help me figure this out, that would be great.

Comment: `table[row][col] += incr;` also `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table));`

Answer (score 1):

inside the loop add this line of code:
table[row][col] += incr;

Comment: I tried that and this is the output I get: 
    What do you want to increment by?
3
345678910111213141516171819202122
23242526272829303132
3334353610023839404142
43444546474849505152
53545556575859606162
63646566676869707172
73747576777879808182
83848586878889909192
93949596979899100101102
So just a bunch of random numbers

Comment: Every time you loop through you are printing out each digit, thats whats causing the numbers